# Photo not saved in location given

Tags: android, camera, storage, photo

I am trying to take a picture in my app, and then redisplay it.   When I start the camera intent, I pass a URI to save the photo location in.   Here is how I create the file:

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US).format(new Date());
String imageFileName = "Waypoint_photo_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
File storageDir = new File(PICTURE_FOLDER);
storageDir.mkdirs();
Log.v("FILE", String.format("New file: %s%s%s", PICTURE_FOLDER, File.separator, imageFileName));
return new File(storageDir, imageFileName);
```

Where picture folder is:

```
public static final String PICTURE_FOLDER = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString() + File.separator + "UtopiaWaypoints";
```

This creates a file similar to:
/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/UtopiaWaypoints/Waypoint_photo_20150718_102116.jpg

In my onActivityResult, I get the file from the same path, and create a thumbnail version of it.   At this point if I look on the device I see the files, but they are in /mnt/shell/emulated/0/Pictures/UtopiaWaypoints:

```
shell@shamu:/mnt/shell/emulated/0/Pictures/UtopiaWaypoints $ ls
Waypoint_photo_20150718_102825.jpg
Waypoint_photo_20150718_102825.png
shell@shamu:/mnt/shell/emulated/0/Pictures/UtopiaWaypoints $ pwd
/mnt/shell/emulated/0/Pictures/UtopiaWaypoints
```

On my device (nexus 6), /storage/emulated exists (neither is a symbolic link), but it only contains a "legacy" folder.

So when I try to load the file later from the /storage/emulated directory (which is what the Environment.PICTURE_DIRECTORY returns, the app can't find the file.

```
// This line outputs something similar to:  /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/UtopiaWaypoints/Waypoint_photo_20150718_1042581116411973.png
Log.v("WPA", String.format("Loading thumbnail from: %s", Utils.getFullThumbnailPath(wayPoint.getPicture())));
Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Utils.getFullThumbnailPath(wayPoint.getPicture()));
wayPointImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
```

The second to the last line (decodeFile) shows this in the log:

```
D/skia﹕ --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
```

imageBitmap is null and the ImageView is blank.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The paths that you see in **`adb shell`** are not the same as the paths seen in the app, because paths get remapped based upon users and such. Both paths point to the same actual location. You are going to need to explain, in detail, what "the app can't find the file" means.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I added the code where I try to load the bitmap from storage.   Basically the decodeFile call is showing that the imageBitmap is null (I assume this means it can't find the file).

Comment: Found my issue.   My Utils.getFullThumbnailPath() method had a bug in it, and was returning a temp file path with extra numbers in the file name.